# wishlist is web app javascript

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, schema

I want to create a wishlist for my app - using node and angular.
I was thinking to create schema dynamically for each user that logs in and then when he clicks on add to wishlist - the item will be added to his schema and he will be able to see all the details.
I want to ask if this way of thinking of implementing it is right?
and if so how do I create a schema for each user?

thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you mean by schema ? why you want to add a separate schema for each user who login. Why not use single schema and use some identification for each user

Shahzad